# Has anyone been able to see a crash attachment with Xamarin Forms and AppCenter.ms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

As far as I know I have followed exactly the instructions:

I have set everything up as suggested. Used my secret key, enabled crashes. Had the set up checked by another developer and see the crash happened in appcenter.ms but still I never see any attached information.

Here's an example:

```
public class Application
{
    // This is the main entry point of the application.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
        // you can specify it here.
        try
        {
            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            Crashes.TrackError(ex,
                new Dictionary<string, string> {
                            {"Main", "Exception"},
                            {"Device Model", DeviceInfo.Model },
                    });
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

No matter what, when and how my application crashes I still will not get the attached information.

I am wondering has anyone got the attached data  for crashes to work with XF ?

Comment: I tested it on both Android and iOS and yes, I can get attached info.

Comment: The code looks fine to me and does not violate the [attachment limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/errors/#limitations). Try to contact AppCenter support directly with that issue.

Comment: VahidShir  - Was that a Xamarin Forms app that you were testing it with?

Comment: @Alan2 yes, it was a Xamarin.Forms project.

Answer (score 4):

We can use AppCenter only after it has been started which according to [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin) on iOS we do it in *AppDelegate* class in the method *FinishedLaunching*. But the point is the class *Application* in *Main.cs* file is called before AppDelegate class.

If you want to see the attached info then you can try it for example in a XAML code-behind file by manually throwing an exception. Here is an example for a button's click event:

```
private void TheButton1_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        throw new DivideByZeroException("Testing attached info!");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Crashes.TrackError(exception,
        new Dictionary<string, string> {{"Device Model", "My device model" }});
    }
}
```

The attached info on TrackError() method i.e properties dictionary works on both Android and iOS. To see that info you need to go through this in App Center's panel:

1. From left panel choose ***Diagnostics***.
2. From ***Groups*** section choose your specific group.

[image]

3. From tabs in top section choose ***Reports***.
4. Choose your specific **device**.

[image]

5. The attached info is In ***Stacktrace*** tab and in ***Error properties*** section.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just to correct, the additional data you attach with exception in TrackError method are mostly in catch blocks or generated exception in TrackError methods, so it will only displayed with those manually logged(TrackError) exceptions.

Crashes are exceptions that are not handled and logged automatically by appcenter so if you look in crash reports there will not be any attached data available.

Additional data sent with exception as properties can be found in reports section of error on appcenter.

I am sure you have initialized Crash service in `OnStart` method of `App.xaml.cs` class with correct app secrets and required platforms(android/ios).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to track the crashes. The only difference is am tracking it from the native projects.

For Android in the MainActivity:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;
    AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += AndroidEnvironment_UnhandledExceptionRaiser;
    ...
}
private void AndroidEnvironment_UnhandledExceptionRaiser(object sender, RaiseThrowableEventArgs e)
{
    var newExc = new Exception("UnhandledExceptionRaiser", e.Exception as Exception);
    LogUnhandledException(newExc);
}

private static void TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs unobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs)
{
    var newExc = new Exception("TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException", unobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs.Exception);
    LogUnhandledException(newExc);
}

private static void CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs unhandledExceptionEventArgs)
{
    var newExc = new Exception("CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException", unhandledExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionObject as Exception);
    LogUnhandledException(newExc);
}

internal static void LogUnhandledException(Exception exception)
{
    try
    {
        Crashes.TrackError(exception);
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // just suppress any error logging exceptions
    }
}
```

For iOS in the AppDelegate:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    ...
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;
    ...
}

private static void TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs unobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs)
{
    var newExc = new Exception("TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException", unobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs.Exception);
    LogUnhandledException(newExc);
}

private static void CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs unhandledExceptionEventArgs)
{
    var newExc = new Exception("CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException", unhandledExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionObject as Exception);
    LogUnhandledException(newExc);
}

internal static void LogUnhandledException(Exception exception)
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch
    {
        // just suppress any error logging exceptions
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that a Xamarin forms application. It's a bit off topic but why would you track it from native ?

Comment: Yes, t is a forms application. That's where I get all the crashes caught globally at once. I am not able to track it at the PCL level, unfortunately.